# chmod the folder to make it writable for the server in php

Tags: php

i am trying to upload a file on server via PHP form. Data is all working find ad getting image name in DB perfectly but issue is that i am not getting image on server.

I googled and found that DIR is not writable. I checked with below code:

```
$image_folder   = $destination_folder . $new_file_name;
if ( ! is_writable(dirname($image_folder))) {
      echo dirname($newFileName) . ' must writable!!!';
}
```

and then to change the permission, i tried using **chmod('$destination_folder',0777)** but all of a sudden a thought striked to mind that should i give write permissions to all on server.

Ideally answer is no but then how can i handle it..??

Comment: I am winging it a bit here, but if the server account cannot write to the directory I would hope that the server account would not be allowed to change the permissions to allow it to write to the directory. Otherwise unix is not as secure as everybody thinks

Comment: you don't need xx77, you just need 0755, or even 0700 if no one BUT the webserver UID needs access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can give permissions 755,

```
7       5     5
user   group  world
r+w+x  r+x    r+x
4+2+1  4+0+1  4+0+1  = 755
```

Comment: This only works if php is owner of the dir! See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know who is the owner. Default makes it sense who creates the folder.

- You can use 755 if php creates the folder (php user is owner: the first 7 = full rights for owner) (recommend)
- *If e.g. ftp user is owner, upload via php user with 755 permissions for dir is not enough: php user **has no write permissions**.*

Answer (score 0):

probably not the answer you're looking for, but if you find that PHP can't write files to anywhere on the filesystem, and you can't chmod a directory for uploads, you could always store the images in the database